# Can DatabaseChangeListener be applied to specific query values?

Tags: java, sql

[We're using DatabaseChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/dbchgnf.htm#JJDBC28820) in our code with certain queries, but for one instance we want the listener to be able to be triggered on the returned value of a query. Specifically, we have a query that returns the number of seconds until a certain action needs to be performed, so we want a listener to be triggered when the number of seconds returned is 0. Is this possible with DatabaseChangeListener?

I tried plugging the query directly in to `stmt.executeQuery( QUERY_STRING );` but that simply resulted in `ORA-29983: Unsupported query for Continuous Query Notification`, which seems pretty vague. Below is the query if it helps.

```
select
  (case
    when ns.daycode is null
      then sysdate
    when greatest(jts.todate(n.transdate) + ns.delay, sysdate, trunc(sysdate)+ns.starttime) < trunc(sysdate)+ns.endtime
      then greatest(jts.todate(n.transdate) + ns.delay, sysdate, trunc(sysdate)+ns.starttime)
    else trunc(sysdate)+1
  end - sysdate) * 86400 as deliverytime
  from notices n
  left join noticeschedule ns
    on (n.noticetype = ns.noticetype and
        n.noticedeliverytype = ns.noticedeliverytype and
        n.instbit = ns.instbit and
        to_char(sysdate, 'D') = ns.daycode)
  where n.noticetype in ('RR', 'RC')
    and n.instbit = 965
    and n.processed = 'N';
```